# Calculating mean, median and standard deviation in stack raster for different time steps

Tags: r, stack, mean, raster

I have a raster brick/stack (using the raster package) in R for 45 years of annual rainfall data from 1970 to 2015. I want to calculate mean, median and standard deviation for a given year e.g. 2015 using the last 5 years, 10 years, 15 years, 20 years, 30 years. 
I want to do it from 2000 to 2015,  where this processes repeated for every year using the stacked data and save the newly derived rasters for a given year. This the example code. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
raster <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
raster_brick <- brick( sapply(1:45, function(i) setValues(r, rnorm(ncell(r), i, 3))))
plot(raster_brick)
str(raster_brick)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To achieve this task, we can use the `calc` function from the raster package. We also need to know how to subset the `RasterBrick` object.

#### Data preparation

```
library(raster)
set.seed(123)
r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
r_brick <- brick(sapply(1:45, function(i) setValues(r, rnorm(ncell(r), i, 3))))
```

#### Example of calc function

`calc` can apply a function for all layers in a `RasterBrick` object. The end result is a raster layer.

```
# Calculate mean
r_mean <- calc(r_brick, mean)
# Calculate median
r_median <- calc(r_brick, median)
# Calculate sd
r_sd <- calc(r_brick, sd)
```

Notice that `r_mean`, `r_median`, and `r_sd` are all `RasterLayer`.

#### Example of subset a RasterBrick

We can use the index to subset the layer. For example,

```
r_sub <- r_brick[[1:3]]
```

`r_sub` is the first three layers of `r_brick`

#### A function to Conduct the Analysis

Knowing the technique of `calc` and subset, we can design a function to conduct the analysis.

The first thing to do is create a vector serving as a reference to year and index.

```
# Create the index
ind <- 1:45
names(ind) <- 1971:2015
```

Calling the year number to `ind` will return the index. For example,

```
# Get the index of 2015
ind[as.character(2015)]
#2015 
#  45
```

Now design the function, which has five arguments

`end_year`: The end year of analysis

`n_year`: The last `n` year in terms of the end year

`FUN`: A function, such as `mean`, `median`, and `sd`

`index`: The year index (`ind`)

`ras_brick`: `RasterBrick` to work with

```
# Define the function

raster_stat <- function(end_year, n_year, FUN, index, ras_brick){
  
  # Subset the raster
  index_temp <- index[as.character((end_year - n_year + 1):end_year)]
  ras_brick_temp <- ras_brick[[index_temp]]
  
  # Calculate the statistics
  ras_result <- calc(ras_brick_temp, FUN)
  
  # Set the name
  names(ras_result) <- paste("Y", end_year, n_year, substitute(FUN), sep = "_")
  
  return(ras_result)
}
```

Now we can test the function.

```
raster_stat(2015, 5, FUN = sd, index = ind, ras_brick = r_brick)
#class       : RasterLayer 
#dimensions  : 10, 10, 100  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#resolution  : 36, 18  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
#data source : in memory
#names       : Y_2015_5_sd 
#values      : 12.05333, 14.61298  (min, max)
```

Notice that the result of the `raster_stat` function has the name `Y_2015_5_sd`. This is helpful to identify which `end_year`, `n_year`, and `FUN` was applied.

#### Apply the function

We can use for loop to apply `raster_stat` through all `end_year` and `n_year`. Here is an example calculating the `mean`.

```
# Set the range of end_year and n_year
end_year_vec <- 2000:2015
n_year_vec <- c(5, 10 , 15, 20, 30)

# Create an empty list to store result
r_mean_list <- list()

for (i in end_year_vec){
  for(j in n_year_vec){
      result_temp <- raster_stat(end_year = i, n_year = j, FUN = mean, 
                                 index = ind, ras_brick = r_brick)
      # Add the raster layer to the result_list
      r_mean_list[[names(result_temp)]] <- result_temp
  }
}
```

All the results are stored in `r_mean_list` with a unique name. We can use the same approach for `median` and `sd`.

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks ycw

Comment: @www , I tried to use your code, but it's not working. All the files saved on the list (`r_mean_list`) have the same values, despite the time step.

Comment: @JoãodosReis Thank you so much for pointing out this error. I made a mistake in my code when defining the `raster_stat` function. I have corrected this error. Please see my update. `ras_result <- calc(ras_brick, FUN)` should be `ras_result <- calc(ras_brick_temp, FUN)`.

Comment: @www, thank you! Now it's perfect. It's going to help me a lot!